# Counting length of div with class separately jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="pam_numbers">18</div>
<div class="pam_numbers">1000</div>
<div class="pam_numbers">1900</div>
<div class="pam_numbers">18</div>
```

I would like to count number of characters in every div separately to create a conditional if value==2 then...

```
$(".pam_numbers").text().length
```

is returning sum of values of every div with class. In this case '12'.

Do I have to add an ID to every div and count from array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to treat each div separately, $(".pam_numbers") selects all of them. One approach is to loop through them jQuery style:

```
$(".pam_numbers").each(function () {
  if ($(this).text().length == 2) {
    // Do stuff
  }
});
```

Other approach would be to capture the array-like object containing all elements that match the selector and then looping through it traditionally.

```
var elements = $(".pam_numbers");
for (var i in elements) {
   // check and do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to apply the condition on each element and returning it, if it satisfies your condition.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzrzz/)**

```
$(".pam_numbers").filter(function(){    
   if($(this).text().length == 2)
       return $(this);    
});
```

**Edit**: As @Mark Schultheiss suggested we can omit `if` by directly putting condition with return statement.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzrzz/1/)**

```
$(".pam_numbers").filter(function(){      
     return $(this).text().length === 2;
});
```

Comment: So simple, yet I didn't came up with it. Thank you!

Comment: or simply `return ($(this).text().length === 2)` leaving out the `if`